# Maven compilation failure error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

When i compile my bdd frame work in java getting the following compilation error.I am new to this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
2:compile (default-compile) on project workflows.automation: Compilation
failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/OFFICIAL/BDDFramework/workflows.automation/src/main/java/bdd
/automation/pages/LoginPage.java:[23,1] package org.jbehave.core
.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/OFFICIAL/BDDFramework/workflows.automation/src/main/java/bdd
/automation/pages/LoginPage.java:[31,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class BeforeStory
[ERROR]   location: class bdd.automation.pages.LoginPage
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `jbehave` core is missing at compilation time. Add jbehave-core into your pom.xml as a new maven dependency.

See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-core

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
      <classifier>resources</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency> Is this correct?

Comment: Just `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>` whith the expected version number